# What is the best unobtrusive and objective method to measure mental workload?

Tags: measurement, methodology, workload

What is the current research/industry standard on measuring mental workload using objective measurements (e.g. EEG, eye-tracking)?

Do you have any suggestions for specific tools and techniques? 
Are there combinations of physiological measurements one should consider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different parameters you can use, but as the question is not clear what exactly you want to do , I think with EEG and Task Load Index (TLI) you are good to go.

> The Task load index (TLI) is the so called engagement-index  and  is 
>   defined  by  two  formulas,  TLI1  and  TLI2. However, these indices
>   were calculated as follows:
>   [image]
>
> where Pθ and Pα denote the theta- and alpha-band power, respectively.
>   Pθ,Fz and Pθ,AFz are the theta activities of Fz and AFz electrodes
>   respectively. The θ (theta) activity was calculated by averaging the
>   power spectrum of the θ frequency range (4-7.5 Hz). Similarly, Pα,Pz
>   and Pα,CPzPOz are the α (alpha) activities of Pz and the pool of CPz
>   and POz electrodes, respectively. The α activity was calculated by
>   averaging the power spectrum of the α frequency range (8- 12.5)

This section is exactly quoted from [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226865851_The_Assessment_of_Heart_Rate_Variability_HRV_and_Task_Load_Index_TLI_as_Physiological_Markers_for_Physical_Stress).

Comment: Sounds like reasonable advice, but there are some caveats, namely that higher TLI seems associated with higher performance: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25277022

Comment: That completely make sense, I have seen paper using LZ as a measure of workload, so it really depends on what r u measuring and what you need it for, the interpretation is really important

Comment: Thanks both for your comments. It’s to compare mental workload between performing a task in a specific simulator where you must read instructions yourself vs when you can discuss task instructions with an equally competent peer. I believe you will have lower levels of WL when you don’t have to communicate with a peer, however perhaps the fact that you can share your task responsibilities actually positively impacts your WL. I’m not sure how to factor in task performance yet.

Comment: Have you designed the task ? the timing is really important for such a task

Comment: I'm currently working with the design, but it will be a well-defined maritime navigation scenario. Interesting, could you please elaborate on your comment about timing, what specifically are you referring to? I really appreciate your consideration.

Comment: I think I have to know more about the experiment, maybe after you finished the design we can discuss about it